# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Spring Boot application deployed as Jar. Need to change Ngnix to allow large files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried the option of adding.platform or .ebextensions folder to the zip file to modify the ngnix setting to allow more than 1MB file but it did not work. I deployed my spring boot as a jar in Elastic Beanstalk. Can you please help me? Appreciate it. Thank you.

Update on the structure. I have used the following directory structures:

1)
root of the zip folder

- .platform

  - ngnix
    - conf.d
    - ngnix.conf
- application.jar
  the contents of proxy.conf are:
  client_max_body_size 100M;

2)root of the zip folder

- .ebextensions

  - ngnix
    - myconf.conf
- application.jar

The content of the conf file myconf.conf:

files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
client_max_body_size 100M;

I have referred to the following links:

1. https://medium.com/innovation-res/how-to-configure-aws-ebs-to-handle-large-files-10411b9cecf0
2. https://dev.to/rasoolk16/elastic-beanstalk-update-media-upload-size-53go
3. https://harishkm.in/2020/08/06/uploading-large-files-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-fails-with-http-413-request-entity-too-large/

Thank you,
Jeelani

Update:

I've tried keeping the config file directly under .ebextensions and used the following formats to try it out.

1. files:
   "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
   mode: "000755"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |
   client_max_body_size 100M;

Noticed the following error:

The configuration file __MACOSX/.ebextensions/._01_nginx.config in application version showkase-source-20 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1, JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (�) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.
2) client_max_body_size 100M;

Let me go through the links you have provided and see what am I doing wrong. Thank you. Will keep you posted. But with either of these formats, I don't see the file appearing in /var/app/current. I see only the applicaiton.jar and Procfile.

Contents of config file:

```
files:
 "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_proxy.conf":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    client_max_body_size 20M;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used two different methods (via `.platform/nginx` hook and via `.ebextensions`). They are both valid, but only one should be needed.

While your platform hook seems fine, the `.ebextensions` is not according to the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). It needs to have the file extension `.config` (not `.conf`) and the file needs to lie directly in the `.ebextensions/` directory (not `.ebextensions/nginx`).

Some hints on debugging if this doens't fix your problem:

- Check the following CloudWatch logs:

  - `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/<yourAppName>/var/log/eb-engine.log`
  - `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/<yourAppName>/var/log/eb-hooks.log`
  - `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/<yourAppName>/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- Log into the EC2 instance via the Session Manager (located at the Systems Manager) to check the following:

  - Do you see all files of your zip in `/var/app/current/`?
  - What is the content of `/etc/nginx/conf.d`?

If this does not help, you can try the method in [this SlackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72414246/how-to-add-platform-in-buildspec-yml-file-artifacts).
There, you will run a platform hook script that writes the config file manually.

**Edit after you have corrected the above errors:**

The contents of your config file seems to be correct. But the error message suggests that you have an invalid file encoding or a special character not matching the encoding (e.g., by copy and pasting from a website). You can use `file 01_nginx.config` to see the encoding. Best you delete the current config file and write it again by hand (without any copy & pasting) to ensure that no special characters sneak in.