# How to add .platform in buildspec.yml file artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, buildspec

How I can include the `.platform` directory in the artifacts of the `buildspec.yml` file?

Background: I want to change the nginx setting `client_max_body_size` on Elastic Beanstalk. I am using CodePipeline to deploy my war file on Elastic Beanstalk.

Below is my repo directory structure:

```
├── .checkstyle
├── .gitignore
├── .platform
│   ├── hooks
│   │   └── postdeploy
│   │       └── 01_nginx.sh
│   └── nginx
│       └── conf.d
│           └── proxy.conf
├── README.md
├── appspec.yml
├── buildspec.yml
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── nginx.sh
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── .platform
    │   └── nginx
    │       └── conf.d
    │           ├── hooks
    │           │   └── postdeploy
    │           │       └── 01_nginx.sh
    │           └── proxy.conf
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── k12
    │   │           └── caap
    │   │               └── service
    │   │                   └── ServiceNAME
```

Edit:
The `buildspec.yml` is not including the '.platform' directory in the `artifact.zip` file. The `proxy.conf` file is not getting added on the server.

buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user

  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean compile package
      
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/*.war
    - '.platform'        
  discard-paths: yes
```

Below are the logs from EC2 /var/log/eb-engine.log

```
[INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks                      
[INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/                 
[INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist                      
[INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/current/.platform/hooks/postdeploy
```

Content of 01_nginx.sh script

```
echo "client_max_body_size 20M;" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Comment: Where is your buildspec.yml with explanation why it does not work?

Comment: @Marcin Added buildspec.yml details

Comment: That's good, but what's wrong with it? Any errors? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: Your project tree shows that you already have `.platform`. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Marcin The issue was `.platform` was not getting added to my build `artifact.zip`. But after removing `discard-paths: yes` it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three misconfigurations and two tips to improve:

- In your `buildspec.yml`, you have set `discard-paths: yes` for the artifact. This means that all files will be put directly in the artifact, subdirectories will be lost. Therefore, your nginx configuration `proxy.conf` will not be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` but `./proxy.conf`. This is the reason why the beanstalk deployment cannot find it.

  Just remove the option `discard-paths: yes` and copy your war files to the root directory (and change the artifact file path accordingly). This way, your war files will be at the same place as before.
- You have given the artifact file path `'.platform'` (with quotation marks). According to the [documentation of the buildspec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html), it needs to be `.platform/**/*` (without quotation marks).
- The same way, you will have to add the files `appspec.yml`, `buildspec.yml` and whatever CodeDeploy or the Beanstalk needs to the artifact file paths.
- I'm unsure why you have another `src/.platform` directory. Just keep in mind that it's structure is wrong since it has the `hooks` directory under `.platform/nginx/conf.d` instead of `.platform`. Under this path, it will also not be found by the beanstalk.
- You have put the script `01_nginx.sh` only in the directory `hooks`, which is for deployment hooks. You probably also want to put it in `confighooks`, see the [documentation on beanstalk hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Currently, the script will not run if the beanstalk needs to deploy again due to configuration changes only during code deployments.

Comment: Thank you. After removing discard-paths: yes it worked. Just to add to your info I have also added execution permissions to my 01_nginx.sh script.